# vZ solver returns segmentation fault

Tags: z3

I am very interested in vZ solver after reading the paper "vZ - Maximal Satisfaction with Z3". I compiled the vZ solver from the unsatable branch at commit 04266fc from https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/tree/unstable. However, vZ returns "Segmentation fault" for several input SMT formulas, one example can be found [here.](http://www.rise4fun.com/Z3Opt/FkcF) However, this example formula can be online solved by Rise4Fun. Maybe the local version of vZ has problems. Could you do me a favor to tell me the commit number of vZ in Rise4Fun? Then I can use it locally. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think I found the answer to my question. I found a runnable vZ solver from http://z3.codeplex.com. It is in the "opt" branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my question. I found a runnable vZ solver from z3.codeplex.com. It is in the "opt" branch.